# redirect before checkout drupal

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7, drupal-commerce

i installed this module, commerce_checkout_redirect, it redirects anonymous users to login form before checking out and returning to the checkout page.

BUT, i want to redirect to user to another page.. where i have to link for sign up.

because i have 2 different signup form for my users, private and enterprise

i opened the `commerce_checkout_redirect.module` and inside i found the `return drupal_goto('user/login')` i changed this to `return drupal_goto('my_url')`

any help will be GREATLY appreciated!
Thank you!

Comment: so yeah, i just changed that `drupal_goto()` to my url, i wonder if this will be lost when the module is update?

Comment: Indeed, it is not recommanded at all to modify a contrib module's code. You should write down your own module to override this one. So, even if it is updated, you keep your own overriding code and modifications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got it right. You can either do the redirection using rules or using commerce_checkout_redirect module.

If you need to redirect it to a custom url, make the changes the module & treat it as a custom module. During up gradation make sure you make changes to this module as well

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own hook that overwrites commerce checkout module ( custom module ) , so its not risks when someone updates the commerce checkout module

There are several other drupal redirection modules after login , that takes user to destination pages.

Optionally you can make use of rules module , where you can define your rule to redirect user to destination page after login